# Website Auto Filling Data

Tags: ajax, magento, caching, web

My website is auto filling in other customers details.

1. Random items will fill the basket which seems to be other customers items
2. Randomly logs you in with other customers details
3. When you go to the basket with your "items" its auto fills in other customers details.

We've switched off Full Page Caching and switched off our Ajax Basket, but still seem to be having issues.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a caching problem. Are you sure that your website or your server doesn't have an other caching mechanism (Varnish, FPC, Nginx cache etc)? To begin with, you can check your headers for an X-Cache header or something like this.

Comment: We have checked and we use Nginx but been using this for 10 years and never had an issue, this issue has only happened since we re-skinned our website. We don't think this is the issue,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed, we had to force Magento to create new values for the frontend cookie Id's.